# Is there a way to update a binary package?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

According to the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch14-04-installing-binaries.html), you can install binary packages (`ripgrep`, `cargo-web`, etc.) by calling `cargo install`. Is there a way to *update* an installed package?

I know I can call `cargo install --force`, but it does not seem to be the right way (`force` does not mean update, just enforce some rules).

Comment: As far as I know, `cargo install --force` is the only way. It's how I've always done it, at the very least.

Comment: The other way is to `cargo uninstall <package>` and then `cargo install <package>`.